# How do You Center a Bundle of Squares Containing Text on the Viewport?

Tags: html, css

I tried creating a bundle of squares which contained information and were centered horizontally on the screen. Not only does the bundle not center, but when text is input into the paragraph tag, it shifts the whole square over.

I would appreciate if an explanation to why it was not working was added as well; I want to learn and not be stuck in a question loop.

```css
.headerText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.subHeaderText {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20rem;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bodyText {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 15rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header_1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  color: #0e0e0e;
}

.eventBoxes {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.eventBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
}

.eventHeader {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.eventBody {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- Events -->
  <section class='headerText'>
    <h2 class='header_1'>Upcoming Events</h2>
  </section>

  <div class='eventBoxes'>
    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>January</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>February</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>March</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>April</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>May</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>June</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>July</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>August</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>September</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>October</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>November</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='eventBox'>
      <div class='subHeaderText'>
        <h3 class='eventHeader'>December</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='bodyText'>
        <p class='eventBody'></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe the desired output a bit more clearly? Do you want to make something like a calender?

Comment: Essentially yes. Each box contains a month, and I plan to put things that are going to happen in that month within the box.

Comment: Would be much easier if you used CSS grid for this. Try something like this https://css-tricks.com/a-calendar-in-three-lines-of-css/

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you want it to look like. Are all the event boxes to be on one line - ie the user will have to scroll horizontally - or are they to be one above the other or do you want to fit as many as possible on the screen horizontally and then have the next ones in the next row or...